# Sorting array of object by name (multi dimensional)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, object

how can i sort a array of objects by name.

Example of how the array is constructed array:

```
     object[] o = new object[items.Count+(row-exists)];
     int i = 0;
     for(i=0; i<items.Count;i++)
     {
    XmlNode item = items[i];

    o[i] = new object[5];
    ((object[])o[i])[0] = Safe(item, "ows_Title");
    ((object[])o[i])[1] = Safe(item, "ows_Column5");
    ((object[])o[i])[2] = ((string)Safe(item, "ows_Column7")).Trim(new char[] {'\''});
    ((object[])o[i])[3] = Convert.ToDouble(Safe(item, "ows_Column12"), provider);
    ((object[])o[i])[4] = Convert.ToDouble(Safe(item, "ows_Column9"), provider);
}
```

i want the 'o' to be sorted based on the value of ((object[])o[i])[0] .

Thank you

Comment: Can't get you question. Could you please ellaborate?

Comment: the array 'o' contains objects with a new array, am I right? I want the 'o' to be sorted based on the value/(string) of the index 0 of the 2nd array. I'm not sure if I managed to explain myself any better.

Comment: Why don't you store your object in generic SortedList, with object's primary key as list's key or choose key as per your requirements?

Comment: Still can't get your requirement.

Comment: So o will be sorted differently on each iteration of i?

Comment: the code above is only to illustrate how o is constructed. ( what kind of data it contains etc.)

I think IndigoDelta answer below is close to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand.  The linq below should do what you require.

```
var sortedResult = o.OrderBy(x => ((object[])x)[0]).ToArray();
```

However, I would look at using a differt data structure.  Can you create a new type to encapsulate what the second array represents?  For example:

```
class MyObject
{
  Safe Title {get; set;}
  Safe Column5 {get; set;}
  String Column7 {get; set;}
  double Column9 {get; set;}
  double Column12 {get; set;}
}
```

You can then use a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) to store the new objects.

Comment: Thanks IndigoDelta, looks like you understand what I'm in need of.

unfortunately I don't have access to linq, and I'm on a 2.x framework.

Comment: I pity the man without access to linq.  You can write your own sorting algorithm if required.  Have a look [some examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/sort-array/). There is a library on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/cssorters.aspx) of sorting algorithms which might help you